# Chrome Extension Messaging Timeout

Tags: google-chrome-extension, timeout, message

I have a tab with, among other stuff, following content:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='whatsoever'" />
```

I also have a plugin running that registers every tab using this technique:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(doStuff);
```

The doStuff-function sends a message to the tab:

```
function doStuff(tabId, changeInfo, tab){

    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {'message': 'content'}, function(response){

        doOtherStuff(response);

    });

}
```

I have a script registered (not seen here), and in that script, this happens:

```
function receiveMessage(request, sender, sendResponse){

    sendResponse({'content': 'responseData'});

}

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(receiveMessage);
```

My problem is that due to the instantaneous refresh, the response times out, and following error appears in the console:

> Could not send response: The chrome.extension.onMessage listener must
>   return true if you want to send a response after the listener returns 
>   (message was sent by extension XYZ).

Why is that, and how can I circumvent this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your **`doStuff function()`** ?

Comment: It is in the background.js, which is registered in the background->scripts part of the manifest. It is the same file where the first code snippet is located.

Answer (score 1):

It says, the function receiveMessage should exit with return true;. Only then the message will continue to be send. On false, it is aborted the moment the function returns. So add return true

see:

> This function becomes invalid when the event listener returns, unless
>   you return true from the event listener to indicate you wish to send a
>   response asynchronously (this will keep the message channel open to
>   the other end until sendResponse is called).

from the doc:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage

```
function receiveMessage(request, sender, sendResponse){

    sendResponse({'content': 'responseData'});
    return true;
}

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(receiveMessage);
```

Comment: is there a timeout for the sendresponse? if I return true and never call sendresponse, will I get any future error because I received many messages and didnt respond them? I searched at google a lot but cant find this answer!